# [ROS2] What's the best way to wait for a new message?

Tags: ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to sync up some behaviors and some data while avoiding callback hell.  What's a good way to effectively wait for a new data on a subscription in a synchronous manner?

Here's the high level of what I'd like to do:

```
start_process_callback() {
    trigger_led();
    wait_seconds();
    leftimage = get_left_image();
    trigger_different_led();
    rightimage = get_right_image();
    result = do_things_to_images(leftimage, rightimage);
    send_result(result);
}
```

Where the LED functions are publishers and the get_image functions block until a new image is received on a topic then return that image.  I hope this helps clarify things.  ROS1 had a wait_for_message, but ROS2 doesn't seem to have anything like that.  The only other alternative I can think of is to have a convoluted state machine in a bunch of nested callbacks, but I'd really rather not do that if possible.

Thoughts?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307370/%5Bros2%5D-what%27s-the-best-way-to-wait-for-a-new-message?/) by [talos](https://answers.ros.org/users/30741/talos/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-10-31

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There's no way to do it right now, but we want to change that, see: https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/issues/520 You can use the C API directly, however. It has a wait set which can wait on one or more subscriptions to be ready and then you can take from them in any order.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2018-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [talos](https://answers.ros.org/users/30741/talos/) on 2018-11-01**:
Thanks for the link!  I notice that this says how to wait without an executor, are there any examples about how to wait with an executor?

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-11-01**:
No, but the solution to that issue I linked to might be that the executor can either spin or wait. Not sure yet.

I know some people are doing it but they've created their own Subscription class in C++ to accomplish it, which isn't ideal.

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2018-11-01**:
If you really want to do it now, perhaps this function from the `rcl` tests will be helpful: https://github.com/ros2/rcl/blob/77ef88a4f6b8af70d3f6a7443ba00c3981a0b559/rcl/test/rcl/test_subscription.cpp#L64-L98

**Comment by [talos](https://answers.ros.org/users/30741/talos/) on 2018-11-04**:
We've temporarily set it up to spin in an executor with multiple threads and manual flags.  Not an elegant solution, but it works fine for now.

**Comment by [bvaningen](https://answers.ros.org/users/39746/bvaningen/) on 2021-05-12**:
What is the status of this now in 2021? I have so far not been able to finding anything on it, so i guess it is still not implemented?

**Comment by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) on 2021-06-30**:
that worked for me in Foxy. Not vouching for any correctness here and this should most likely be added to subscription class itself upstream:

```
rclcpp::WaitSet wait_set;
wait_set.add_subscription(subscription);
auto ret = wait_set.wait(std::chrono::seconds(10));
if (ret.kind() == rclcpp::WaitResultKind::Ready) {
  std_msgs::msg::String msg;
  rclcpp::MessageInfo info;
  auto ret_take = subscription->take(msg, info);
  if (ret_take) {
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), "got message: %s", msg.data.c_str());
  } else {
    RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "no message received");
  }
} else {
  RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "couldn't wait for message");
}
```